# storing SNPs in the genotype file for each chromosome in a separate file

Tags: python, perl

I have already asked this question in another forum but have not got an appropriate answer, so wondering if anyone here can help me?
I have a big file with over 3 million columns (SNPs genotypes) and 800 rows (one row for each individual).

The first row is the SNPs_ID name with the SNP position on each chromosome (see the example below please), in total there are 17 chromosomes. I want to extract SNPs for each chromosome and store them in a separate file.
I have done it with "R", but I am looking for a faster solution and I am wondering if anyone can help me to figure out another solution with bash, perl or python codes?

here is an example of my input file (SNPs on chromosome 1,2,3,4...,17)

```
"Ha412HOChr01:180159" "Ha412HOChr01:210724" "Ha412HOChr01:303270" "Ha412HOChr01:303280"....... "Ha412HOChr17:303402"
0 1 0 0 ......0
0 1 0 0 ......0
0 1 0 0 ......0
0 2 0 0 ......0
0 1 1 1 ......1
0 2 0 0 ......0
```

and this is an example of my desired output for example for chromosome 1:

```
out.chrom1
"Ha412HOChr01:180159" "Ha412HOChr01:210724" "Ha412HOChr01:303270" "Ha412HOChr01:303280" 
0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 
0 2 0 0 
0 1 1 1 
0 2 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 2 0 0
0 1 2 2
```

Comment: Hi, good question but perhaps post your R code?

Comment: Are the leading spaces part of your input file? Does the second row, for example really start with 4 spaces? If not, please [edit] and remove them to avoid confusion. Also, are those really the IDs? Do they all start with `Ha412HO`, then `Chr` and number(s), followed by `:` and the position? Or can the `Ha412HO` change?

Comment: I just edited my question according to your comment. And yes, the IDs start with Ha412HOChr followed by chromosome, the : and SNP position

Answer (score 2):

I believe a `pandas` approach would be fast enough (probably faster than any other Python approach without pandas).

After converting your table to a `pandas data frame`, you can do something like `df.filter(regex=(".*Chr01"))` for the first chromosome then write the resulting data to file with the `to_csv()` method.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('input.txt', delimiter = "\t", index_col = False)

for i in ["Chr01", "Chr02", "Chr03"]:
    regex_pattern = ".*" + i
    print(data.filter(regex=regex_pattern))
```